# How to implement Front() method to return the first element of a templated doubly linked list C++?

Tags: c++

Whenever I implement the front() method (to return the first element of the doubly linked list) in the main I get a segmentation fault even though the back() method (returning the info of tail) that was implemented in a similar manner works. Can someone help?

```
template <class T>
class Node {
    public:
    T info;
    Node<T>* next;
    Node<T>* prev;

    Node(const T info){
        this->info = info;
        next = NULL;
        prev =  NULL;

    } 
    Node* getNode(T info){
        Node* newnode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    }
};

template <class T> 
class DLlist {
    private:
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;
    int size;

    public:
    DLlist();
    T front();
    T back();
};

template<class T> 
DLlist<T>::DLlist(){
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    size = 0;
}

template <class T> 
void DLlist<T>::addback(const T newdata){
     if (isEmpty()){
        Node<T> *newnode = new Node<T>(newdata);
        head = tail = newnode;
        size++;
        return;
    }

    Node<T> *newnode;
    newnode = new Node<T>(newdata);
    newnode->prev = tail;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    tail->prev = newnode;
    tail = newnode;

    size++;
}

template <class T> 
T DLlist<T>::front(){
     return (head->info);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of using your classes that results in a crash?

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but front should either be `const T DLlist<T>::front() const` or `T& DLlist<T>::front()`, but really you need both. And if everything in the Node is public, just make it a `struct`.

Comment: `Node* newnode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));` -- Don't ever use `malloc` to create templated instances based on a type you don't know about.  Your code falls apart if `T` is a non-POD type, such as `std::string`.

Comment: I'll also note that the code you've uploaded is incomplete. This makes it hard to reproduce.

Comment: A nice consistent crash is almost a godsend. Sure, it's not as good as the program working correctly, but it's far better than an incorrect program looking like it's working correctly. Run the program in whatever debugger came with your development environment. The debugger will halt when the program crashes and you can inspect the wreckage. The function's pretty simple, so make sure `head` makes sense. You might want to add on a test for and throw an exception on empty.

Comment: `DLlist<int> list1;
    list1.addback(8);
    list1.addback(9);
    std::cout << list1.getNumElements() << std::endl;
    
    list1.addback(1);
    std::cout << list1.getNumElements() << std::endl;
    list1.removefront();
    std::cout << list1.getNumElements() << std::endl;

    std::cout << list1.front() << std::endl;
    std::cout << list1.back() << std::endl; ` when I printi list1.front() it is showing segmenation fault.

Comment: Hey its working now, thank you so much for the clarification.

Comment: `front` should check for `head == NULL`

Answer (score 2):

In your `addback()` function:

```cpp
    Node<T> *newnode;                // Two lines where
    newnode = new Node<T>(newdata);  // one suffices
    newnode->prev = tail;
    newnode->next = NULL;  // Unnecessary, your constructor did this
    tail->prev = newnode;  // THIS IS YOUR PROBLEM
    tail = newnode;

    size++;
```

Your tail should be setting its next pointer to the new node, not its previous. Drawing this stuff out on a piece of paper can go a long way in better understanding how it should work.

I am always willing to chalk up poor formatting on this site to copy/paste, but there are other things you can do to simplify your code, make it a bit more modern, etc.

So here's your code again, cleaned up a tad (This code went through clang-format using the Webkit style):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct Node {
    T info;
    Node<T>* next = nullptr;
    Node<T>* prev = nullptr;

    Node(const T& info)
        : info(info)
    {
    }
    // Don't know why you need this, so just deleting it because it's a bad
    // function
};

template <class T>
class DLlist {
private:
    Node<T>* head = nullptr;
    Node<T>* tail = nullptr;
    int size = 0;

public:
    DLlist() = default;
    bool isEmpty() { return head == nullptr && tail == nullptr; }
    void push_back(const T& newdata);
    const T front() const;
    const T back() const;
};

template <class T>
void DLlist<T>::push_back(const T& newdata)
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        head = new Node<T>(newdata);
        tail = head;
        size++;
        return;
    }

    Node<T>* newnode = new Node<T>(newdata);
    newnode->prev = tail;
    tail->next = newnode; // THIS WAS PROBABLY YOUR ISSUE
    tail = newnode;

    size++;
}

template <class T>
const T DLlist<T>::front() const
{
    return head->info;
}

template <class T>
const T DLlist<T>::back() const
{
    return tail->info;
}

int main()
{
    DLlist<int> list;
    list.push_back(42);
    list.push_back(54);
    std::cout << list.front() << '\n';  // 42 prints just fine, Debian w/ LLVM 9
}
```

Comment: I will add that the front and back functions are assuming that the list is not empty. That's typically a very bad thing to do, and they should throw an exception. I didn't add all that because there's no indication that you are required to or have learned about exceptions yet (Although I feel like you should have before tacking data structures)